Physic issue direction with shop bag
I have an issue with shop bags in particular with the center raw that doesn’t fall down correctly with gravity and cause some issue in the final part.

As second error the raw on the right gives issue with the second group of shop bags

As third issue I have a problem in the left side

As mechanism I use 3 cubes that gives direction that goes up when the wind will do force

As version I used Blender 4.1.1 and I tried also Blender 4.2 and it gives similar problem, here below you can find Blender file and the final animation with this problem:
https://we.tl/t-mHowHyBmGh
