Wind force makes central shop bag row fall down incorrectly
I have a problem with central shop bag row that basically falls down.
In particular I applied three raw and each one is connected to make the shop bags fall down correctly:

Cube 1 with the left raw
Cube 2 with the central raw
Cube 3 with the right raw

And after all the shop bags fall down there is a force applied called "Wind" that pushes out the shop bags, but causes some issues with the central one
Animation physics problem (2 MB size):
https://we.tl/t-qL4qqoyqD0
As rigid body I applied as passive:

Cube 1 (passive)
Cube 2 (passive)
Cube 3 (passive)
Plane (passive) - that is invisible

As active I applied:

Shop bags


Physics problem:



Does could be great now as post

Please don't ask the same question more than once! https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/321885/physic-issue-direction-with-shop-bag. If you don't get an answer, try editing and adding more details to your question rather than posting it again! See How to ask a good question. Incidentally, I think you mean "shop bag row" rather than "raw"!

This question is similar to: Physic issue direction with shop bag. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's different, because it gives a different problem, the first one is the entire row, now is only center, because I fixed the other two
